# Undefined variable argc PHP

Tags: php, linux

I'm trying to execute this code:

```
function main(){
  if ($argc < 1){
    listDir(".");
  }
  else{
    for($i = 0; $i <= sizeof($argv); $i++){
      listDir($argv[$i]);
    }
  }
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: argc in /home/me/test.php on line 15

I thought that $argv and $argc were global variables. How can I get rid of this error?

I'm running this from command line.

Comment: `$argc` and `$argv` are auto-populated only when running from the command line. Are you running this script from the command line?

Comment: +1 @GeorgeCummins I was just about to ask the same

Comment: I'm running this from command line

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Add a

```
global $argc, $argv;
```

after

```
function main() {
```

Those variables are in global scope, but not in your function's scope. The global keyword imports them.

Comment: Those variables are globals. So it's rather pointless to declare them global again.

Comment: @Bart this answer is good - even though it's global - if you want to use it inside a function you should declare it as such.

Comment: The global keyword imports global variables in your local scope. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php The first example in that page is exactly this.

Answer (score 7):

You probably want to do:

```
$argc = $_SERVER['argc'];
$argv = $_SERVER['argv'];
```

Comment: Why? An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22095162/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

You can run the following command.

```
php -i | grep argv # Run this command
```

It will output this:

```html
<tr><td class="e">register_argc_argv</td><td class="v"> Off</td><td class="v"> Off</td></tr>
```

This means your PHP interpreter is not registering *argv* and *argc*.

If it is off, you can go to your *php.ini* file and set it as `register_argc_argv = On`.

This solved my problem.